# How to interpret Regex subtraction with grouping

Tags: regex, xml, namespaces

I would be grateful if someone could explain how the following regex should be interpreted; it is from the W3C reference for [Namespaces in XML 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#NT-NCName), and defines an NCName ([4]) as:

Name - (Char* ':' Char*)    /* An XML Name, minus the ":" */

I can understand subtraction when applied to lists, such as:

[a-z-[aeiuo]] representing the list of all consonants (see http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html), but not when applied to a group (apologies if this is the wrong term) as shown above.

The comment indicates how I should interpret the regex, but I'm struggling; why not just:

```
           Name - ( ':' )
```

if the intention is for NCName to be [Name](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name) minus ':', then why are the zero or more characters required on either side (I'm not asking a separate question, just indicating my area of confusion)?

Please accept my thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not a `regex`, it is the [BNF Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form). The notation is also explained [in the document](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-notation) you are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documents published by [W3C](http://w3c.org) use a variant of the [`EBNF` Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) to describe the languages standardized by them.

It is described in section ["6 Notation"](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-notation) of the [XML Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/).

The example you posted:

```
NCName ::= Name - (Char* ':' Char*)  /* An XML Name, minus the ":" */
```

How to read it:

- `NCName` is the object described by the rule;
- `::=` separates the name of the described object (on the left) by the expression that describes it (on the right);
- `Name` is an object already described by [another rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name);
- `-` is the except symbol; `A - B` in `EBNF` means "matches `A` but doesn't match `B`";
- `(...)` - the parentheses create a group; they make the expression inside them behave as a single item;
- `Char` is another object already described by [another rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Char) in the documentation; it basically means a Unicode character;
- `*` - repetition, matches the previous item zero or more times;
- `':'` - string in single or double quotes is a string literal; it represents itself; here, the colon character;

Put together, it means a `NCName` is a `Name` that doesn't contain `:`.

The comment seems incorrect (or maybe it is just bad worded).

Comment: To qualify this answer, the dialect of EBNF used is defined in section 6 of the XML Recommendation, and differs in many details from the notations described in the Wikipedia article cited. There are many dialects of EBNF in use.

Comment: @MichaelKay of course it is defined in the XML Recommendation. I had it in front of my eyes when I wrote the answer. I thought I put the link to it into the answer but it seems I forgot. Thank you for mentioning it.